# Perl Net::SSH2 for Windows

Tags: perl

```
use Net::SSH2;

$HostName=$ARGV[0];
my $ssh2 = Net::SSH2->new();
$ssh2->connect("$HostName") or die "Unable to connect Host $@ \n";
$ssh2->auth_password('user','passwd') or die "Unable to login $@ \n";
my $chan = $ssh2->channel();
$chan->shell();
print $chan "cd C:\Test\n";
```

The above code doesn't seem to be working for windows box. Can anyone please tell me the issue?

Comment: Are you sure the *windows box* is running an SSH daemon?

Comment: What exactly does *"doesn't seem to be working"* means? Is there any error?

Comment: SSH connection is working.

Answer (score 0):

Enable warnings with "use warnings;" and you will immediately find at least one error.

Comment: the problem above was that I need to use double backslash for C:\\Test. Now the problem I am facing is- I want to trigger setup.cmd from that location but it doesn't seem to be working since expected logs are not generated. Command I executed was: print $chan "setup.cmd\n"; I tried "use warnings", but no error message is displayed.

Comment: seems like Net->SSH2 doesn't work for batch/cmd scripts for windows.

Comment: create a file there manually and see if a simple "del" commmand works?